# BizTalk Admin Console - Error Saving Properties - Trying to change WCF-Custom basicHttpBinding to use SSL

Tags: ssl, biztalk, wcf-security, biztalk-2010

I had a SendPort/Webservice working with http.  I then changed the webservice to require SSL, changed the web.config, and got it working from SOAP-UI.

Now I want to change my existing SendPort to use SSL. I tried changing the Mode under "BasicHttpBindingElement/Security" to Transport (in BT2010), and it gives the error:

> Error Saving Properties: (System.InvalidCastException) Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'Microsoft.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement'
>   to type 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BindingCollectionElement'.

Do I have to change the SendPort to WCF-BasicHttp? 
Am I doing something wrong, or is this perhaps a bug in Biztalk Admin Console?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I did have a custom behavior on another SendPort in the project.  I took that out, because it wasn't being used.  It's possible it wasn't installed properly (i.e. not in the GAC) on the server that was giving the problem.  Then I was able to make the change above and it worked with no error.

But then when I ran I got this error (I had seen this before, but got past it with SOAP-UI and a port that uses basicHttp binding):

> Details:"System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no
>   endpoint listening at https://mysite/myapp/myservice.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)

So it looks for now, I will go with basicHttp binding.